# No payment sheet has been initialized yet

Tags: ios, flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-ios, flutter-stripe

**main.dart**

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Stripe.publishableKey = stripePublishableKey;
  Stripe.merchantIdentifier = 'emailID';
  await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
```

**Initiate Payment**

```
Future<void> initPaymentSheet({
  required String? price,
}) async {
  try {
   await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
      paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
        // Main params
        paymentIntentClientSecret: clientSecret,
        customerId: customerId,
        customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,
        // Merchant Name
        merchantDisplayName: 'TEST',
        // Extra params
        applePay: const PaymentSheetApplePay(
          merchantCountryCode: 'US',
        ),
        googlePay: const PaymentSheetGooglePay(
          merchantCountryCode: 'US',
          testEnv: true,
        ),
        style: ThemeMode.system,
      ),
    );
  } catch (e) {
    rethrow;
  }
}


/// Display the payment sheet.
Future<void> confirmPayment({required String price}) async {
  try {
    await initPaymentSheet(price: price);
    // Present Payment sheet to user for payment
    await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();

    // Book the request.
    bookingRequest();
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    if (e is StripeException) {
      // displaySnackBar(
      //     'Error!', 'Error from Stripe: ${e.error.localizedMessage}');
      log('Error from Stripe: ${e.error.localizedMessage}');
      print('Error from Stripe: ${e.error.localizedMessage}');
      displaySnackBar('Error!', 'Something went wrong!, \nPlease try again.');
    } else {
      log('Error from Stripe: $e');
      displaySnackBar('Error!', 'Something went wrong!, \nPlease try again.');
    }
  }
}
```

- This **confirmPayment()** is called on Button click.
- It will wait for Init the payment sheet.
- After that **presentPaymentSheet** called to present the Payment sheet.

**In Android, It's working fine.
In iOS, it's showing error like: No payment sheet has been initialized yet**

Already Raised the Issue on the plugin Repo.
https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/850

Comment: Can you give more context and share more of your code, to better understand the issue? For example where is this function called from?

Comment: @soma Edited the question with more detail.

Comment: I would recommend calling `await initPaymentSheet(price: price)` earlier in your code, for example when the page loads. If that doesn't solve the error then I don't know, hopefully the Github Issue you opened will provide you a solution.

Comment: @soma Okay,
Let me try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

✅ **Solved:**

Okay, the problem was in our backend response
when we were generating EphemeralKey, our backend dev was returning ephemeralKey["id"] instead of ephemeralKey["secret"] as a ephemeralKey.

I changed the EphemeralKey

from this
 `paymentIntentDTO.setEphemeralKey(ephemeralKey.getId());`

to this
`paymentIntentDTO.setClientSecret(paymentIntent.getClientSecret());`

see ephemeralKey is different.
ephemeralKey["id"] is work fine in android app for stripe payment but on IOS ephemeralKey["id"] will not working
it was showing Error from Stripe: No payment sheet has been initialised yet

i changed ephemeralKey["id"] to ephemeralKey["secret"] as a ephemeralKey and now it working fine on both device.